# Create a function that receives a list of parts and rebuild this list to a single string that respects the following constraints

Tags: python

Create a function that receives a list of parts and rebuild this list to a single string that respects the following constraints :

- there is only one part in this list that starts with 'A'
  and so there is only one part that ends with 'Z'
- So the string returned by the function *rebuild_parts* must start with the first part, and must finish with the last part.
- the first part, is the part of the list that starts with 'A'
- the last part, is the part of the list that ends with 'Z'
- if any part ends with the first character of the following part, one of those parts has to remove this character,  example : ["link","king"] going to be "linking"

**Examples**:

*input :*
`mystring = rebuild_parts(["link", "king", "Apple", "ziZ", "left", "turn"])`
*output :*
`ApplelinkinglefturnziZ`

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions before posting homework questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this solution works for me :

```
def rebuild_parts(parts):
  for i in parts :
    if i[0]=="A":
      first_part=i
    elif  i[-1]=="Z":
      last_part=i
  parts.remove(first_part)
  parts.remove(last_part)

  for i in range(len(parts)-1):

    if parts[i][-1] == parts[i+1][0]:
      mylist = list(parts[i+1])
      mylist.remove(mylist[0])
      parts[i+1]="".join(mylist)

  if first_part[-1] == parts[0][0]:
    tmpllist = list(first_part)
    tmpllist.remove(tmpllist[-1])
    first_part = "".join(tmpllist)

  if last_part[0] == parts[-1][-1]:
    tmpllist = list(last_part)
    tmpllist.remove(tmpllist[0])
    last_part = "".join(tmpllist)

  mystring=first_part
  for i in parts :
    mystring=mystring + i
  mystring=mystring+last_part
  return mystring
```

**Testing   **
*input :*

```
mystring = rebuild_parts(["link", "king", "Apple", "ziZ", "left", "turn"])
print(mystring)
```

*output :*

`ApplelinkinglefturnziZ`